# jquery calling variable after ajaxcomplete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

The whole idea is to limiting the number checkboxes through dropdown, the approach is: 
I have dropdown with following code

```
<select name="form[norequnit][]" id="norequnit" class="rsform-select-box">
  <option value="">...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<input name="chk" type="checkbox" class="bd-lable"  value="9432"><label>01</label>
<input name="chk" type="checkbox" class="bd-lable"  value="9432"><label>02</label>
<input name="chk" type="checkbox" class="bd-lable"  value="9432"><label>03</label>
<input name="chk" type="checkbox" class="bd-lable"  value="9432"><label>04</label>
<input name="chk" type="checkbox" class="bd-lable"  value="9432"><label>05</label>
<input name="chk" type="checkbox" class="bd-lable"  value="9432"><label>06</label>
```

And some check boxes which are loading by ajax and below code is running to get dropdown value and also after ajax part to limit the number of selection based on the selected dropdown,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $("#norequnit").on("change", function () {
 $('#unitcount').html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
 });

 $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {

     $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );

        var nux = $('#unitcount').text();

        $("input[name=chk]").change(function(){

    var max= nux;

    if( $("input[name=chk]:checked").length == max )
        {
            $("input[name=chk]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $("input[name=chk]:checked").removeAttr('disabled');
        }           
        else{
            $("input[name=chk]").removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        })
   });

   });
  </script>
```

*Problem:*

variable "**nux**" get value only in first attempt by selecting dropdown, for example 5 so you to limit the boxes to 5 checks, but after this if you change dropdown to any other number the checkbox limitation remains on 5, in other word "**nux**" wont get new variable.

Comment: Why would nux change?  You don't have any sort of change event handler to capture that event and update it accordingly.  Otherwise, make nux be the select object itself, instead of it's value, and any time you need the value just do nux.text() or nux.val(), whatever, and it will reflect what it is at that point in time.

Comment: nux is getting value from unitcount on first dropdown change and its working correctly. but after that by changing dropdown unitcount is changing but nux its not updating.

Comment: Right, i addressed why in my first comment.  Javascript does not inherently two way bind javascript variables with dom elements.  You have to either manage that state reflection yourself, or reference the dom element instead which will always be up to date with itself.

Comment: can you update the code please?thanks

Comment: What about my statement confuses you?  Instead of `var nux = $('#unitcount').text();` it's just `var nux = $('#unitcount');`  and then in your comparison below it changes to `max.text()`

Comment: Oh it works like a charm thanks, now i understand.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things wrong with your code, I'll try and go through them piece by piece with explanations and fixes.

## Select `onChange` handling:

1. Separate your data from your view
2. Use `val()` instead of `text()` to get a select's current value

Code:

```
var nux; // 1. This will hold the value of nux for use in your script

$("#norequnit").on("change", function () {
    nux = $(this).val(); // 1. Save the data, 2. Use using val()
    $('#unitcount').html(nux); // 1. Use the data
});
```

## Do you really need to use `ajaxComplete`?

I don't think `ajaxComplete` is the right way to go about responding to an ajax call (I could be wrong, I don't have all your code in front of me). Below I've done a best guess as to what you should (maybe, probably) do.

Code:

```
// Assuming you've got your ajax call somewhere else, use the "success" 
// handler instead of the "ajaxComplete" function

$.ajax({
    url: yourUrl,
    method: 'get',
    data: {
        param1: 'value1',
        param2: 'value2', // etc
    },
    success: function(html) {
        // Presumably this is the HTML for your checkboxes, so add them
        // to the DOM
        $('#norequnit').after(html);

        // And the only thing that really should go here otherwise is
        // your bit of debug logging
        console.log("Triggered ajax success handler.");
    }
});
```

## Use `console.log` if you are just outputting debug text

Maybe you actually do want to print the message on the page, if so you can ignore this. At very least, be aware of this wonderful debug-enabling tool. You can hit F12 (developer console) in your browser to view the output.

```
console.log("Triggered ajaxComplete handler.");
```

## Move your checkbox `onChange` handler outside of any ajax closures

You could run into some incredibly hard to debug issues otherwise.

Code:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="chk"]', function() {
    // Handler code here
});
```

Notice the slightly different call to `on`, which uses the `document` object and includes the context parameter. This ensures any objects added to the DOM *after* the event handler is registered will still be handled.

## All of it together

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     var nux;

     $("#norequnit").on("change", function () {
        nux = $(this).val();
        $('#unitcount').html(nux);
     });

     $.ajax({
         url: yourUrl,
         method: 'get',
         data: {
             param1: 'value1',
             param2: 'value2', // etc
         },
         success: function(html) {
             $('#norequnit').after(html);
             console.log("Triggered ajax success handler.");
         }                
     });

     $(document).on("change", 'input[name="chk"]', function() {
         if ($('input[name="chk"]:checked').length == nux) {
             $('input[name="chk"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
             $('input[name="chk"]:checked').removeAttr('disabled');

             // Alternatively you could do this:
             $('input[name="chk"]').not(':checked').attr('disabled', true);
         } else {
             $("input[name=chk]").removeAttr('disabled');
         }
     });
});
```